Finding fixed energy trajectories between two points
I am trying to plot the fixed energy trajectories for motion in a potential $ V(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}x^2y^2 $ from the initial point $(x=1, y=0)$ to the final point $(x=0, y=1)$. The equations of motion are $\ddot{x}(t) = -y(t)^2 x(t)$ and $\ddot{y}(t) = -x(t)^2 y(t)$, and the energy is set through this equation: $\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) + V(x,y) = E$. However, I cannot use NDSolve because I do not know the initial speeds (first derivatives) that take me from the initial to the final point, and I also do not know $t_{final}$. How should I go about solving this problem in Mathematica?
Thanks in advance.
Edit: As pointed out in the answers there was a minus sign missing in my EOM which I have corrected.

First I think your equations of motion aren't correct. Lagrangeformalism with T==1/2 (x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2)and V==1/2 x[t]^2y[t]^2 gives equations of motion {x''[t] == -y[t]^2 x[t], y''[t] == -y[t]  x[t]^2 .
You might solve your problem using ParametricNDSolveValue with parametrized initial velocities vx,vy
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -y[t]^2 x[t],y''[t] == -y[t]x[t]^2, 
x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == vx, 
y'[0] == vy}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {vx, vy}]

With this general solution we now try to fit the point x[tfinal]==0, y[tfinal]==1
J[vx_?NumericQ, vy_?NumericQ, tfinal_?NumericQ] := # . # &[Through[sol[vx, vy][tfinal]] - {0, 1}] 
NMinimize[ J[vx, vy, tfinal], {vx, vy, tfinal}] // Quiet
(*{1.97371*10^-16, {vx -> -0.772452, vy -> 0.88713, tfinal -> 1.22134}}*)

Hope it helps!

Hi, thanks for the helpful answer. How do I see the energy condition in this code? It seems to choose some E for some t_final.

@amy Thanks. You might plot the energy over time. Alternatively there is an NDSolve-option Method -> {"Projection",    "Invariants" ->      1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 1/2 x[t]^2 y[t]^2  }
